# Initialize Django Form with Parameters from Previous Page

Tags: python, django, forms, gis, geodjango

New to Django and everything was going smoothly until this...

I am trying to pass latitude / longitude to a django form when user clicks on map.

Here is the js for my map page:

```
mapview.on("click", function(event) {
            // Get the coordinates of the click on the view
            // around the decimals to 3 decimals
            var lat = Math.round(event.mapPoint.latitude * 100000) / 100000;
            var lon = Math.round(event.mapPoint.longitude * 100000) / 100000;
            openForm(lat, lon);

function openForm(lat, lon){
        window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/form';
        alert("latitude: "+lat+" and longitude: "+lon);
}
```

And my **forms.py**

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    created_date = forms.DateTimeField() 
    userid = forms.CharField()
    description = forms.CharField()
    latitude = forms.CharField()
    longitude = forms.CharField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #instance = kwargs.get('instance', None)
        kwargs.update(initial={
            # 'field': 'value'
            'latitude': 'this text will initially populate...',
            'created_date': 
        })
        super(MineralForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

and **views.py**

```
def mineral(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = MineralForm(request.POST) # populates form with what user tried to submit...
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.created_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()

            return render(request, 'blog/matMap.html')  

    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!!!

Comment: You need to use javascript form data to pass a http/post to your django function. The code seems fine. but your javascript needs a better way to send the form value.  BTW you need also to pass csrf_token if the case. else use @ csrf_exempt above your def mineral as a decorator

Comment: Thank you eddwinpaz this is working too! I am going to keep playing with this, but it seems to be working great. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to pass lat/long to your form as query parameters, e.g.:

```
// I was in a hurry, but make sure to url encode these
function openForm(lat, lon){
    window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/form?lat=' + lat + '&lon=' + lon;
    alert("latitude: "+lat+" and longitude: "+lon);
}
```

Now, in your view, you have to unpack these values from the `request` and initialize the form with those values.  You can add initial values to a [django form with `initial` argument](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.initial).  We use `latitude` and `longitude` as the field names because those are the field names used in the `MyForm` definition.  We accessed the query parameters using `lat` and `lon` because those were the names we used in the javascript.

```
    def mineral(request):
        form = None
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = MineralForm(request.POST) # populates form with what user tried to submit...
            if form.is_valid():
                post = form.save(commit=False)
                post.author = request.user
                post.created_date = timezone.now()
                post.save()

                return render(request, 'blog/matMap.html')  

        if form is None:
            lat = request.GET.get('lat')
            lon = request.GET.get('lon')
            if lat is not None and lon is not None:
                form = MyForm(initial={ 'latitude': lat, 'longitude': lon })
            else:
                form = MyForm()
        return render(request, 'form.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Please upvote and/or mark as correct if this helped.